# Scheduler to do some tasks on time

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am working on a scheduler to do certain tasks like send email to users etc. Its a basic one which runs every 5 mins and do its job. I need to make some modifications into that so that it can work on demand. For example, I need to send email to a user at 11:00 AM, to another user at 11:02 AM. How can I make the scheduler to run on time without using a lot of resources on server. I know if I need to send emails every minute, then its sleep time should be one minute or less.

Is there any way to call it on demand or I need to have one thread active all the time to check when to do what and at that time activate scheduler or other process responsible for sending email.

Please suggest. Your inputs will be valuable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send emails every minute it would be better to create a service and have the service poll the database every minute to look for work and sleep for 1 minute in between loops.

If you only need to run your code once an hour it would be better to use the Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Brian. My scenario is bit different. Email sending is just an example and it can be done at any time, one minute pause will not work for me. There can be thousands of records in the table and going through those every minute will not work.

Comment: In that case a multithreaded service that sends email as fast as possible and logic that checks for new emails at the end if the last batch would be best. I wrote an email service that sent about 500k emails a day using this logic with no problems.

Comment: yes, that will work.I'll modify code accordingly. Please let me know if it would not take a lot of resources on server

Comment: The only time a significant amount of resources would be used is when a lot of emails are sending large attachments. Even if you're sending 30 emails at once there is a lot of back and forth between the server running the service and the email servers that you're sending emails through (connecting, logging in, sending the email, disconnecting).

Comment: The only problem we had was with too many connections to Gmail from one server. They seem to limit the number of concurrent connections by IP address and we kept hitting the limit. (Not a resource issue). I would make the number of threads a setting, so you can dial it up/down easily if performance is an issue.